# Product of expected values

Tags: probability

Let us assume to have the following quantities:

1. $\sum_{i \in I}p_i = 1$, with $0 \le p_i \le 1$ for all $i \in I$
2. $\sum_{i \in I}q_i = 1$, with $0 \le q_i \le 1$ for all $i \in I$
3. $0 \le a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i \le 1$ for all $i \in I$

Is it true that

1. $\sum_{i \in i} p_i * a_i \le \sum_{i \in i} q_i * b_i$ and
2. $\sum_{i \in i} p_i * c_i \le \sum_{i \in i} q_i * d_i$

imply

$\sum_{i \in i} p_i * a_i * c_i \le \sum_{i \in i} q_i * b_i * d_i$

?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I doubt it. Have you tried any examples?

Answer (score 2):

$p_1=1$, $p_2=0$, $q_1=q_2=1/2$, $a_1=c_1=.9$, $b_1=d_2=.8$, $b_2=d_1=1$.